# Changing NNID on Mario Edition New 3Ds

Tags: nintendo-network-id, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I got a New Nintendo 3DS system, it is a Mario edition so it comes with Super Mario 3D Land preinstalled. I, stubbornly, decided to created my Nintendo account and NNID in my home region, Colombia; this means that the eshop is pretty much dead, I can only get updates.

My only games are Pokemon Sun, ToZ A Link Between Worlds, and my preinstalled Mario. I want to format my console, to create a USA account and have access to a good eShop, VC, Pokebank and be able to buy Xenoblade Chronicles 3D. My only concern is that I might lose Mario, I know that my save from Pokemon and Zelda will be saved in the cartridge, so no problem in there; what I am not sure about is if ***will I be able to re download Mario for free ?*** (I don't care my about my progress there, but if it can be saved better haha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to re download it for free.